# game is not recognized by game center - no 'sandbox' game center login

Tags: objective-c

I've been implementing the game center functionality for my app but when I test it on an actual device (adhoc version), the game center login pops but it's not the sandbox version.

So to summarize:
1. adhoc version works on my actual device
2. achievement works on my simulator with 'sandbox' game center login popup
3. adhoc version has game center login popup but it's not 'sandbox'
4. so sign in with a new account in the adhoc version results the error: 'game is not recognized by game center'

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks,
Mars

Comment: Are you using the beta sdk? I know this is a documented issue for iOS 6 sdk.

Comment: Hi Dustin, nope i'm using iOS 5.1 sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this issue is that my phone is jailbreaked